# How to start ,stop and change listening port on Hyperledger Playground?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

On the [documentation](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/using-playground-locally.html) shows how install Hyperledger Playground locally, but not how to start, stop and change listening port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for pointing this out.

you can run the dockerized Composer Playground on a different port using the following command:
`docker run --name composer-playground --publish 9999:8080 --detach hyperledger/composer-playground`

that is - it will make playground available on `http:/localhost:9999` (if running on localhost etc etc!) - The 'publish' syntax above is  `externalport:internalport`  - the internal port (8080) inside the playground container remains the same, and its just port forwarding to the 'externalport'

So - substitute external port with the port of your choice (above).

Comment: That works but I cant create a new profile because Composer Playgrount can't find the directory("Error: Failed to load connection profile hlfv1. Error was Error: ENOENT: No such file or directory., '/.composer-connection-profiles/hlfv1/connection.json"). I think the problem is because its dockerized so it has no visibility of the file system

Answer (score 0):

You can get ID of current Composer-playground process by below command:

> ps -elf | grep composer-playground
>   and kill the process by Pkill -s process-id

Then, you can use the below command to launch playground in another port:

> composer-playground --port new-port